# The name of a frame in a loop

Tags: vba, excel

I want to add a Control in every for in my application. Let's say I have 5 frames...
I want to do someting like this:

```
Set cControl = Me!iooly&i.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "str12" & i, True)
    With cControl
        .Caption = "1/2"
        .Width = 20
        .Height = 8
        .Top = 10
        .Left = 435
    End With
```

i is a counting variable
the problems is that Me!iooly&i ... Can I do this operation when my frames have names la iooly1, iooly2, iooly3 and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Me` is presumably a form? This won’t work. Also, the `Me!iooly&i` syntax doesn’t work, this only works if your string is a constant.

You can use the `Forms` collection though:

```
Set cControl = Forms("iooly" & i).Controls.Add(…)
```

This is assuming that the form already exists. If it doesn’t, you need to first load it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The forms were created with a For loop ...now I want to do another For loop to add some controls in every one of them. I'll try your advice to see how it works! Thanks again!

Comment: I made a big big mistake... I said forms but I was reffering to frames!